# Get size of folder without iterating over its content?

Tags: filesystems, directory

Is there any unix file system (or network fs) that can get size of folder without iterating over its content?

I need the fastest and cheapest way to get size of folder (maybe some fs cache metadata on nodes?), iterating over its content is too slow.

Comment: Some more details would improve this question.  For instance, how are you currently determining size?  Are you reading in the files and counting the bytes or just reading the metadata?  Also, how slow is "slow"?  Actual numbers here are important.  You may have reached the limits of your physical disks and only changing those will help (RAID, 15krpm, SSDs, all of the above, etc.).  Your measuring methodology will be important too.  It's very easy to get misleading performance data about disks thanks to the filesystem cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linux only answer]
If there is a specific set of folders you want to measure fast you could try to use:

- separate filesystems/mountpoints (e.g. on LVM to ease management), then use df to get size. Be aware that df on some filesystems are not 100% accurate.
- XFS project quotas and then see disk usage by `xfs_quota -x -c "report -p"`. You can assign huge disk space or disable quota enforcements by using `uqnoenforce` mount option.

Personally I would go to XFS project quotas on kernels that do support it.